# add new key value for every dict of dict with list of dict

Tags: python

I have dict of dict:

```
a = {
    'a': {'id': 1},
    'b': {'id': 1},
    'c': {'id': 1}
}
```

And list of dict:

```
b = [{'word': 'foo'}, {'word': 'baz'}, {'word': 'bar'}]
```

I need update every dict from a to every value key word from b

Example:

```
a = {
    'a': {'id': 1, 'word': foo},
    'b': {'id': 1, 'word': baz},
    'c': {'id': 1, 'word': bar}
}
```

i try do it by the next way:

```
[
a.update(
    {
        'word': i
    }
)
for a in a.values()
for i in [
    df['word'] for df in b
    ]
]
```

but i have all new keys with last word bar:

```
    a = {
    'a': {'id': 1, 'word': bar},
    'b': {'id': 1, 'word': bar},
    'c': {'id': 1, 'word': bar}
}
```

How i can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the first answer...but along with your thinking, you just needed to get an index from enumerating the dictionary and use that to index the list.

```
a = {"a": {"id": 1}, "b": {"id": 1}, "c": {"id": 1}}

b = [{"word": "foo"}, {"word": "baz"}, {"word": "bar"}]

c = [
    value.update({"word": b[index]["word"]})
    for index, (key, value) in enumerate(a.items())
]

print(a)
{
    "a": {"id": 1, "word": "foo"},
    "b": {"id": 1, "word": "baz"},
    "c": {"id": 1, "word": "bar"},
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `zip` to iterate over `a` and `b` concurrently:

```
for k, d in zip(a, b):
    a[k].update(d)
```

Result:

```
{'a': {'id': 1, 'word': 'foo'}, 
 'b': {'id': 1, 'word': 'baz'},
 'c': {'id': 1, 'word': 'bar'}}
```

You can also use `a.values()` as one of the arguments to `zip`:

```
for d1, d2 in zip(a.values(), b):
    d1.update(d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works and uses a dictionary comprehension instead of a `for` loop:

```
a = {
    'a': {'id': 1},
    'b': {'id': 1},
    'c': {'id': 1}
}
b = [{'word': 'foo'}, {'word': 'baz'}, {'word': 'bar'}]
a = {k:{**a[k], **d} for k, d in zip(a, b)}
```

Result:

```
{'a': {'id': 1, 'word': 'foo'},
 'b': {'id': 1, 'word': 'baz'},
 'c': {'id': 1, 'word': 'bar'}}
```